# How to create a PyDriver in blender 2.7

Tags: python, drivers

I've heard of PyDrivers where you can put python code into a driver, & I'm wondering, how would you do that in blender 2.7x without resorting to a lower blender version?

Here's what I'd like to put in the driver:

```
(ob(‘Armature’).getPose().bones[‘Bone.001’].head - ob(‘Armature’).getPose().bones[‘Bone’].head).length/250
```

Comment: i think it's the same as normal driver just use 'scripted expression'

Comment: I've tried putting in a short python script in the expression field when using 'scripted expression' but then I get an 'Invalid Python Expression' error

Comment: can you post this code line ?

Comment: @ISaenz Your only supposed to write a _one_ line snippet - I think that's why you get an error

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/48158/2843

Answer (score 8):

your example can be implemented as in the following driver :

[image]

but for more complex drivers refer to [this DOC page](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/drivers/workflow_examples.html#driver-namespace) , the important part is that you can define your function and add it to driver namespace as in this example :

```
import bpy

def driverFunc(val):

    return val * val    # return val squared

bpy.app.driver_namespace['driverFunc'] = driverFunc    # add function to driver_namespace
```

now you can use it the driver scripted expression