# Running a script for each frame

Tags: python, scripting

If there is an object which has a property that which varies with each frame, would it be possible to to build a script that can access that property before each frame is rendered and thus change another property?

Comment: It does seem to answer the question of running the script before rendering. But would it be done before each frame is rendered?
Also I'm new to scripting.

Comment: You could try using calling this function: `bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post` with a function as a parameter. Check the API here: http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_60_6/bpy.app.handlers.html

Comment: Could you provide your current script, so I can modify it to do what you want?

Comment: Sorry but I have no script. I'm thinking about creating an addon and I wanted some knowledge of how to do so.
Thanks for the offer, I'd really like to collaborate with someone sometime in the future.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One way is by [using drivers](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Basics/Drivers). Drivers allow you to calculate a value to use, this may be from other values in the same object, or from other objects. [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/27056/935) provides examples. Also consider that [drivers may be disabled](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Extensions/Python/Security) by the user.

Another way is to setup a [handler function](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_0/bpy.app.handlers.html). You could choose between using `frame_change_post` or a `render_pre`. You simply define your function and then append it to the handler list, then remove it when it is no longer needed.

```
def my_handler(scene):
    val = scene.objects['Cube'].location.x
    scene.objects['Sphere'].location.y = val + 1.6

def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(my_handler)

def unregister():
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.remove(my_handler)
```