# Detecting light intensity on surface with cycles nodes

Tags: node-editor

Are there any methods for detecting the light intensity on the surface of an object using cycles nodes? Ideally including light from hdri and all other sources.

[image]

Comment: What is the purpose? Any render contains full colour depth info before save (if I'm right). So like Matte > Luminance Key in Compositor is what are you looking for?

Comment: I was hoping to use it as a driver for automating light dependent animations like pupil dilation. Perhaps the data could be extracted from each frame before beginning the next frame using the compositor and some scripting.

Comment: Hm ... from your Q I red -you'r looking for post-pro, but from this info it seems you want affect mesh or material animation before rendering, right? Please extend your Q via *edit* with these details (delete my gif if its wrong or too much :)

Comment: is this direction? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/29094/2214