# Essentially, what are drivers?

Tags: drivers

Okay, so I'm a relatively new user of Blender. I've delved into most of Blender already, including the Graph Editor and F-curves, but not the Dope Sheet or Drivers.

I'm planning to get into what the Dope Sheet is later on, but for now, I wondered what drivers are...?

What can they be used for?
How can I use them?
Are they Engine-specific?
(I usually use Cycles.)

Thank you.

Comment: Drivers are ways of controlling certain properties based on the values of other properties or scripted Python expressions.

Comment: Thanks guys! I should probably read the manual a bit more :) although I sometimes find it overwhelming to read and not very well explained.... Or rather, so well explained I don't understand it :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A driver is a Python expression that is used to control the value of some field, generally depending on some external variable. They're generally limited to one line, but [can actually span many](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34117/can-drivers-span-more-than-one-line).

> Drivers can use properties, numbers, transformations, and scripts, to control the values of properties.
>
> Using a F-Curve, the driver reads the value of the Driver Value and sets the value of the selected property it was added to.

<sup>From the Manual entry: [drivers](https://www.blender.org/manual/animation/drivers.html#drivers)</sup>

F-curves are just an easier way to animate a property overtime, by manipulating the handles that define a function that maps time to some value. Then, Blender interpolates for the values between the handles.

> The idea is simple: you define a few Key Frames, which are multiple frames apart. Between these keyframes, the properties’ values are computed (interpolated) by Blender and filled in. Thus, the animators’ workload is significantly reduced.

<sup>From the Manual entry: [f-curves](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/graph_editor/fcurves.html)</sup>