# What are Blender driver used for?

Tags: animation, drivers

I just discovered that drivers are scripts that is written for animations. I cant seem to find a decent tutorial about drivers. How useful are drivers and can you give me some cases where drivers csn be useful?
Cheers

Comment: This may be of help https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/drivers/introduction.html

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43078/essentially-what-are-drivers. I personally use them often to basically establish link between properties, and that's a big thing!