# Can I use the distance between two objects to animate a property?

Tags: objects, camera, compositing-nodes, properties, blur

I would like to make the value of a node, say a blur node, influenced by the distance between two objects (say a camera and a cube) with blender render engine.
How would you achieve that?

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43078/essentially-what-are-drivers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes, with [Drivers](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/drivers/introduction.html)

You can animate a property with a combination of values of other chosen properties.

To set up a Driver, just right click in the parameter field and choose "Add Driver"->"Manually create later" from the pop up menù. In the following example I added a "value" node and linked and added a driver to control it's value (the purple one), but I might have directly controlled the Size parameter of the Blur node itself:

[image]

In the Graph editor, under the Driver editor type, you can easily set up a Distance Driver Type and pick the two objects (camera and cube in the following example):

[image]

Here's the result:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!