# How can I drive the Switch nodes True/False value?

Tags: python, compositing-nodes, video-sequence-editor

In the compositor I would like to add a driver to the Switch Node. I want to watch a frame value from a VSE strip.
When the current frame count equals the Strip start frame I want to switch the node.

Here is an example of what I hope to achieve:

- When current frame is less than `abs(var)+var_001` then pass no picture,
- if current frame is greater than `abs(var)+var_001` then switch source through.

Of course what I have entered is unformatted nonsense. And the switch node expects to return a `true` or `false`, not a value.

*nb: `abs(var)` changes negative number to integer.

[image: Example switch driver concept]

Can I define the `abs(var)+var_001` (it is the VSE strip trimmed start time) as a function of some sort to call elsewhere? It's a pain to define it all the time.

Comment: `abs(var)` doesn't change a value into an integer value (which are only natural numbers), but gives their absolute value, which is the same like *multiplying by -1 if negative* or in other words *removing the negative sign if applicably*.

Comment: Oh and the "trimmed start time" of a Strip is probably already available to you via its `frame_final_start` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I was only grabbing paths from the variables exposed in the Strip Properties, I never thought to use any of the other properties.

Comment: To find out, which attributes exist from a given Property, just copy the Path like `bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].sequence_editor.sequences_all[0].` including the following `.` into a *Python Console* Editor view and hit *Ctrl* + *Space*. The autocompletion feature will suggest you all available ones.

Comment: Is there something you're still missing in my answer below?

Comment: Oops, sorry I forgot to tick it. I don't ask very often so this is a bit new to me. Thank you for your help Samoth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me with the plain Expr: `abs(var) < frame`. So basically you just need a Boolean expression (omit the `if` in your expression) for it to drive the Switch. Basically any numerical result below 1.0 will result in `Off` and starting from 1.0 and above will result in `On`.

You can put something like `(abs(var) < frame) and (abs(var) + var_001 > frame)` into the box to evaluate only `True` during the duration of your Strip after you changed your `var_001` to the `frame_final_duration`.

Furthermore you could [Copy'n'Paste](https://www.blender.org/manual/animation/drivers.html#copy-paste) drivers if you want to use them again.

When you want to use your own function to add more complicated stuff like conditional expressions, stick to the Example code in the documentation about the [Driver Namespace](https://www.blender.org/manual/animation/drivers.html#driver-namespace):

> This script will add a function to the driver namespace, which can then be used in the expression `driver_func(frame)`:
>
> ```
> import bpy
>
> def driver_func(val):
>     return val * val    # return val squared
>
> # add function to driver_namespace
> bpy.app.driver_namespace['driver_func'] = driver_func
> ```

But giving your variables meaningful names as soon as possible is a good practise... ;-)

Comment: Can also use `1 if (expr) else 0`  .. unnecessary  for booleans handy for returning other values, eg `10 if(var > frame) else 99`

Comment: Kind of... I updated the answer, you need to use a function for this. Don't forget to upvote ;-)

Comment: Can I define a name for variables in the driver window to use on other drivers? I thought you could only do that in text editor as a script. EDIT: oh i see so I define name via script which i can use in the driver entry

Comment: The variable names in the driver window should match with the ones in the function (in your script), otherwise it should work as well when you assign them directly in the function call like `var + function(var=frame)`. But when there is only one variable that explicit name assignment might be omitted like in the example where frame in the driver properties will be assigned to var inside the function for calculation... The python documentation should help you out here... ;-)

Comment: Come on - what was the reason for a downvote here again?

Comment: " Basically any numerical result below 1.0 will result in False and starting from 1.0 and above will result in True."  Clarification on this, are you saying bool(0.9) and bool(-1) equate to False?

Comment: No, not when you use the `bool(x) -> bool` function (Returns True when the argument x is true, False otherwise.) and I didn't say this - but when you put these values into the Scripted Expression field in the driver to drive the Switch Node you'll see that it does so...

Comment: See what you mean, it either works as you say or throws an error `TypeError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: SomeObjectType.some_bool_prop expected True/False or 0/1, not float` Think I'll  stick  with using 0/1 or True/False for on / off.

Comment: @3pointedit related: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jvFqhDE_vW8&feature=youtu.be ;-)

Comment: Ummm, thanks... thats me! I made the video after all of the help that I got here. Thanks everyone :D

Comment: I'd like to say thank you because your answer and batFINGER's comments pointed me in the right direction. I needed an Integer slider with possible values 1, 2, 3, to be the driver that activated and deactivated 3 constraints. I wanted value 1 to activate constraint 1 (and deactivate constraints 2 and 3), value 2 to activate constraint 2 (and deactivate constraint 1 and 3), and value 3 to activate constraint 3 (and deactivate constraints 1 and 2). These are the three I used:
(1 if (1==(your_var_here)) else 0)
(1 if (2==(your_var_here)) else 0)
(1 if (3==(your_var_here)) else 0)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to say thank you because your answer and batFINGER's comments pointed me in the right direction. I needed an Integer slider with possible values 1, 2, 3, to be the driver that activated and deactivated 3 constraints. I wanted value 1 to activate constraint 1 (and deactivate constraints 2 and 3), value 2 to activate constraint 2 (and deactivate constraint 1 and 3), and value 3 to activate constraint 3 (and deactivate constraints 1 and 2). These are the three scripted driver expressions I used, one in each of the 3 constraints:

`(1 if (1==(your_var_here)) else 0)`

`(1 if (2==(your_var_here)) else 0)`

`(1 if (3==(your_var_here)) else 0)`

You can modify this for greater than, less than, greater than or equal to, or less than or equal to with:

`<,>,<=,>=`