# Change cloth end_frame in python script

Tags: python, scripting, cloth-simulation

I am trying to run a cloth simulation in blender using python scripting and despite setting the frame_end of the scene to the desired number of frames (`C.scene.frame_end = total_frames`), the cloth stops at 250 frames.

I eventually found that that I need to set the frame_end for the cloth as well, and I tested it and it works, but I don't know how to do the same operation via scripting.

Here is a screenshot of the particular setting I am trying to change.
[image]

When I change the setting via the user interface, the following appears in the info view mode:

```
bpy.context.object.frame_end = 285
```

However, when I try to do the exact same thing via the python console, blender will give me the following error:

```
>>> bpy.context.object.frame_end = 285
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Object' object has no attribute 'frame_end'

>>> bpy.context.object
bpy.data.objects['shirt']
```

When I hover over the property, the "command" that pops up is also incomplete:

```
bpy.data.objects['shirt'] ... frame_end
```

How do I change this property via scripting?

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49123/why-is-copy-data-path-path-different-from-the-tooltips-path) That is a tricky one, it's `context.object.modifiers['Cloth'].point_cache.frame_end` (where the cloth modifiers name is "Cloth" and the object has context)

Comment: Hmm @batFINGER that has no effect for me, I was not able to change the frame_end. Was this changed in a recent version of Blender? (I'm using 2.82a.) I can post a MWE if needed.

Comment: Works for me.. added as answer.

Comment: Thanks! I had a really dumb mistake when testing the code. I'll up vote you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It is a setting of the added cloth modifier.**

[image]

```
context.object.modifiers['Cloth'].point_cache.frame_end
```

(where the cloth modifiers name is "Cloth" and the object has context)

The tooltip is spot on in later versions of blender.

Note may have to mouse over properties area to redraw and see new value.