# Interlace frame numbers with file output node

Tags: scripting, compositing-nodes, video, file-browser

I have a setup in the compositor that takes a piece of footage, does some operations, and outputs 3 difference files. Let's call them output A, B, and C. I have the file output node with added sockets to output each. What this gives me in the output folder is each output followed by the frame number. For example, frame 1 will give me A-0001.png, B-0001.png, C-0001.png.

What I would like is to alter the frame number appended to the output files so that instead I would have A-0001.png, B-0002.png, C-0003.png. Frame 2 would then give A-0004, B-0005, C-0006.

The end result would triple the number of frames of the animation and have them interlaced.

Is this possible with the file output node? Is it possible with a script?

Comment: I think, the frame number will only be added if you don't specify the complete filename but omit the ending (the file suffix like *.png*). However, you might script a complete filename including your desired frame numbers via a [driver function](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/48158/2843). You should be able to calculate your frame number via `(bpy.context.scene.frame_current - 1) * 3 + output_offset` (with *output_offset* being *1..3* for *A..C*. in your custom function.

Comment: The File Output node seems to add the frame# and format regardless. If I tell it the output is A.png, it'll give me A.png0001.png.

Comment: I have the same issue :(
Seems no way to stop blender appending the exact frame number to the filename.

Comment: Setting `render.use_file_extension=False` removes the extension, but the frame number is still added.

Answer (score 1):

I'm maybe wrong but it seems there is no way to avoid Blender (2.8) to remove the frame number and the extension of the filename with `CompositorNodeOutputFile` object, as I'm rendering by a python script I finally fixed it by renaming the files with `os.rename` combined with a regular expression just after render.