# How can I switch connected Falloff nodes on a keyframe?

Tags: node-editor, keyframes, animation-nodes

I have an an animation setup that uses a Falloff node to animate my scene into view and at a set frame I want another Falloff node to handle the fade out of the object but right now I have to manually connect the node at my desired frame.

**FADEIN**:

The Offset Matrix node is set to ***End*** and the object fades into view.

[image]

**FADEOUT**

The Offset Matrix node is set to ***Start*** because I want the object to exist and then **Falloff** by reducing its scale. I can keyframe the Offset Matrix node's options but I have to manually connect the FADEOUT Falloff node and continue from that frame. I'm sure there is a better way to do this but I've been unable to solve it.

Is it possible to switch connected Falloff nodes on a keyframe?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I continued my SOW browse and came across a post that mentioned the **Switch** node. I combined this with a **Compare** node using the **Time Info** node and I have exactly what I needed.

Credit to [3pointedit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/1218/3pointedit) for asking this question [How can I drive the Switch nodes True/False value?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48157/how-can-i-drive-the-switch-nodes-true-false-value)

[image]