# Can we execute custom Python functions from driver expressions?

Tags: python, scripting, drivers

I have a simple function that I'd like to call from a driver Python expression.

[image]

I've run the script to define the function, but it doesn't seem to be accessible from the driver expression.

```
Error in Driver: The following Python expression failed:
    'myDriverFunction()'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<bpy driver>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'myDriverFunction' is not defined
```

Is it possible to modify the namespace in which drivers execute?

Comment: you have to append it to the driver name space

Comment: see this http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27053/how-to-create-a-pydriver-in-blender-2-7

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your custom driver must add itself to the list of drivers BPY is aware of.
See the example here:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/drivers/workflow_examples.html#driver-namespace

```
import bpy

def driverFunc(val):

    return val * val    # return val squared

bpy.app.driver_namespace['driverFunc'] = driverFunc    # add function to driver_namespace
```

Comment: Also be sure to run the script to have it apply.